# Can't migrate ~50Mb MYSQL database to Azure App Service + MySQL in app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-mysql-database

Hi I am having an issue importing my database to the Azure App Service MySQL in app. My database is around 50Mb, and when I try to import the database I see that it fails to import. I suspect that this is due to a limit on maximum size allowed for import. Please help me identify whether or not this is true, what the max default size is, and if possible, how to increase this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There is an upload limit of 8 MB by default.
This can be changed by following below steps:

1. Please create a user.ini inside the wwwroot of the web app
2. Inside this file, place "upload_max_filesize = 100M" and "post_max_size = 102M"
3. Then stop/start the web app and try to upload the database again

This issue is referenced as #3 in the following blog, and other troubleshooting for MySQL in App can be seen here too: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/09/08/Troubleshooting-FAQ-for-MySQL-in-app.html

The above steps mentioned can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-windows#Customize-non-PHP_INI_SYSTEM%20directives